# How to duplicate part of tags in XML in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, json

I have this JSON template

```
{ 
    "shipToAddress":{ 
        "country":"SE", 
        "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com", 
        "zipCode":"${zipcode}"
        }, 
    "itemLines":{ 
        "itemLine":[ 
            { 
                "bundleParentId":"", 
                "id":"IL1", 
                "itemType":"ART", 
                "itemNo":"${Article}", 
                "requiredQty":10, 
                "unitOfMeasure":"Piece" 
            }
        ] 
    }, 
    "checkCapacity":"true", 
    "checkInventory":"true", 
    "businessUnit":{ "type":"STO", "code":"856" } 
}
```

In the above example I have to add the complete element "Itemlines" again the template, could some help me pls. The final template should be like the below,

```
{ 
    "shipToAddress":{ 
        "country":"SE", 
        "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com", 
        "zipCode":"${zipcode}"
    }, 
    "itemLines":{ 
        "itemLine":[ 
            { 
                "bundleParentId":"", 
                "id":"IL1", 
                "itemType":"ART", 
                "itemNo":"${Article}", 
                "requiredQty":10, 
                "unitOfMeasure":"Piece" 
            }
        ] 
    "itemLines":{ 
        "itemLine":[ 
            { 
                "bundleParentId":"", 
                "id":"IL1", 
                "itemType":"ART", 
                "itemNo":"${Article}", 
                "requiredQty":10, 
                "unitOfMeasure":"Piece" 
            }
        ] 
    }, 
    "checkCapacity":"true", 
    "checkInventory":"true", 
    "businessUnit":{ "type":"STO", "code":"856" } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the first thing is that this is JSON, not XML.

Could you provide the code sample that produced this data structure? I think it could use some work.

Comment: This json request is an Input, so it is defined by developers, whatever I provided the request for single article now I need to duplicate the part i showed again for multiple articles

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your expected addition to the template is incorrect and would error out as invalid JSON. Unless the system allows multiple `itemLines` objects, you really want to be adding a second `itemLine` to the to the `itemLines` array.

Some basic JSON terminology:

- An element is in the form `"something"` - think of this as the string equivalent in other language
- An object is in the form `{"thing1":"value","thing2":value"}` - this is made up of key:value pairs, similar to a map or dict in other languages
- An array is in the form `[{"a":1, "b":2}, "element"]` - is an array that can hold various items, seperate by commas

In your template you have:

- a shipToAddress object;
- an itemLines object which contains an

  - itemLine array of objects implied to be item lines;
- a checkCapacity element;
- a checkInventory element; and
- a businessUnit object.

To add extra itemLines your JSON should look more like this:

```
{ 
    "shipToAddress":{ 
        "country":"SE", 
        "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com", 
        "zipCode":"${zipcode}"
    }, 
    "itemLines":{ 
        "itemLine":[ 
            { 
                "bundleParentId":"", 
                "id":"IL1", 
                "itemType":"ART", 
                "itemNo":"${Article}", 
                "requiredQty":10, 
                "unitOfMeasure":"Piece" 
            },
            { 
                "bundleParentId":"", 
                "id":"IL1", 
                "itemType":"ART", 
                "itemNo":"${Article}", 
                "requiredQty":10, 
                "unitOfMeasure":"Piece" 
            }
        ] 
    }, 
    "checkCapacity":"true", 
    "checkInventory":"true", 
    "businessUnit":{ "type":"STO", "code":"856" } 
}
```

You should also consider passing in ID as a variable, or you could be violating a constraint elsewhere.

Comment: Nice answer - I might clarify a little that a a JSON element is a quoted string, e.g `"element"`,  object is  `{"key1":"value1"}` and an array is `["item1","item2"]`.  The current examples in the second paragraph are in `"something":<type>` pairs, which is a little misleading

Comment: Good point - I'm a bit short of time right now, but if someone wants to clean up my examples a little, they're more than welcome.